# Multiple applications Symfony2 in a single nginx vhost

Tags: symfony, nginx

I’d like to separate my main app and XHR requests on a Symfony2 project.

Here are my regular Sf2 controllers :

- `https://www.example.com/*` => `/web/app.php/*`
- `https://www.example.com/app_dev.php/*` => `/web/app_dev.php/*`

But I’d like to add XHR requests like that (on the same domain, to avoid CORS issues) :

- `https://www.example.com/xhr/*` => `/web/xhr.php/*` (no dev environment required)

I’m trying to create a nginx vhost, but I don’t find the correct way :

```
server {
    listen 443 default_server ssl;

    server_name www.example.com;
    root        /var/www/example.com/current/web;

    include ssl_config.conf;

    location /xhr {
        try_files $uri /xhr.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|xhr)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass            127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;

        include fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the error when you're restarting your nginx or when your accessing your url ?

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration will strip pathinfo during the redirect. Perhaps you should use:

```
try_files $uri /xhr.php$uri$is_args$args;
```

or simply:

```
try_files $uri /xhr.php$request_uri;
```